# Firebase authentication successful but returns a null user (Web)

Tags: javascript, html, web, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am having trouble authenticating users using firebase with my web application. Whenever I attempt a login the firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass); function is called, the request is successful and the authStateChanged listener is triggered. However, inside the listener firebaseUser always returns null.

I have tried hosting the web application from a personal server and allowing the domain access to my firebase DB.

I also have an android application that works flawlessly with the same DB.

Here is my code:

login.js:

```
(function() {

    // Initialize Firebase
      var config = {
        //CONFIG INFORMATION HERE
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);

      // Get elements

      const txtEmail = document.getElementById('username');
      const txtPassword = document.getElementById('password');
      const loginButton = document.getElementById('loginButton');

      loginButton.addEventListener('click', e => {

        const email = txtEmail.value;
        const pass = txtPassword.value;
        const auth = firebase.auth();

        const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
        promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));
      });

      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
        if(firebaseUser){
            console.log(firebaseUser);
        }
        else{
            console.log('not logged in');
        }
      })

}());
```

login html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Athlete Buddy Login</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="allStyleSheet.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="login.css">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="pictures/ABLogo.png">
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/live/3.1/firebase.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<nav>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Login</a>
    <a href="#">Features</a>
</nav>

<img src="pictures/loginArt.png" id="loginTitle">

<div id="loginFormDiv">
    <form id="loginForm">
        Username: <input id="username" class="field" type="text" name="Username"> <br><br>
        Password: <input id="password" class="field" type="Password" name="Password"> <br><br>
        <input id="loginButton" type="submit" value="Login">
        <a id="createAccountButton" href="#">Create Account</a>
        <a id="forgotPassword" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ">forgot password?</a>
    </form>
</div>

<script src="login.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems unlikely that auth would fail, without triggering the `catch()`. Can you set up a reproduction of it in a jsbin, so I can have a look?

Comment: https://jsbin.com/sonenup/1

Comment: I have never used jsbin before, it is likely that I did that wrong Login Credentials: overflow@gmail.com password: testing123

Comment: Sorry one more thing, [here](http://cs.tru.ca/~kbehiels268w7/athlete-buddy/athlete_buddy_login.html) is where I am hosting the website for development testing

Comment: The jsbin was perfect. I just spotted your mistake, will post an answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning anything from your button click handler, nor preventing it's default behavior. This means that the button submits the form, which leads to a page refresh.

The solution is simple enough:

```
  loginButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const email = txtEmail.value;
    const pass = txtPassword.value;
    const auth = firebase.auth();

    const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
    promise.then(u => console.log(u));
    promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));

    return false;
  });
```

I also added an extra `then()` handler, which makes it easier to see that it's working. But you really should handle the auth state in `onAuthStateChanged` like you were already doing.

See this jsbin: https://output.jsbin.com/waxixe/1